# I am using the select2 plugin. How to make the selected option after clicking on the SEND not fought?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I have such a problem .. in the localStorage of the Sahranet there is only one selected element and after append at   it is duplicated

```
<form method='GET'>
            <select class='select' multiple='multiple'>

            <option value='a2'>aladin</option>
            <option value='3s'>ark</option>
            <option value='4a'>asdasdtaktak</option>
            <option value='5f'>ametis</option>

            </select>

            <input type='submit' value='send'>

    </form>
```

$(document).ready(function($){

```
     $('.select').select2({});
     $('.select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
        var data = e.params.data;
        testObject={ 
        'id': data.id,
          'text':data.text
          }

          localStorage.setItem("lastname",   JSON.stringify(testObject) );

    });

       if(localStorage.getItem('lastname')){

         var data=   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastname'));

          console.log(data.id );
         var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, true);
          $('.select').append(newOption).trigger('change'); 
       }



    });
```

Comment: Try `new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);` to not select the option when appending: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

Comment: in this case, I can not see the selected item

Comment: I solved the problem like this..$('.select').val(data.id).trigger('change');.)))..  but save to localStorage multiple items fail((